# Get latest record with certain criteria in linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have following result set. How to get latest History records which meets criteria : Status = 'A' in linq ? Grouping is done on Entity Id and Records will be sorted descending on History Id

```
History ID  Entity ID   Status
2969        6957        I
2968        6957        A
2967        6957        A
2303        6957        I
1000        6958        A
55          6959        A
50          6959        I
45          6960        I
40          6960        A
```

Results should give me

```
History ID  Entity ID   Status
1000        6958        A
55          6959        A
```

Comment: Why are you only expecting to receive two results? You appear to have 5 records that meet the `Status = 'A'` constraint you provided. Is there another constraint you are missing?

Comment: Hi Rion, the latest history record with history id : 2969 for Entity Id 6957 has status I, so this record should not be selected. Similar is case with Entity Id 6960

Comment: Alright, that's helpful. [D Stanley's response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37687465/557445) should accomplish what you are looking for. I just wanted some additional clarification as it was rather unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first group by entity and get the "latest" records for each group.  Finally check for a status of `A`:

```
histories.GroupBy(h => h.EntityId)
         .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(h => h.HistoryID)
                       .First())
         .Where(h => h.Status == "A");
```